# Cakephp url routes

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

My current url is

```
baseUrl/categories/category/categoryName/subcatName...
```

To convert this url into

```
baseUrl/categoryName/subcatName...
```

i am using following route

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Categories',
        'action' => 'category'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug'),
        'slug'=>'[a-zA-Z]+'
    )
);
```

but it is creating problem with urls like:

```
baseUrl/home
baseUrl/myaccount ..
etc.
```

and redirect them to category action.

Comment: Not much of a surprise - if you want a catchall route like that the simplest solution is to declare all your other routes _first_.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to this problem is to add a single letter (like Reddit).

```
baseUrl/r/slug/something-awesome
```

That way, you can make the route:

```
Router::connect(
'/r/:slug/*',
array(
    'controller' => 'Categories',
    'action' => 'category'
),
array(
    'pass' => array('slug'),
    'slug'=>'[a-zA-Z]+'
)
);
```